# Printing a webpage using selenium in VBA

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, printing, bots

I am trying to print a webpage using selenium in VBA. I want the bot to be able to press control+P and then Enter on the printing dialog but keep getting an object required error. Anyone have any ideas?

```
Sub printing()

    Dim bot As New WebDriver, controlP As Variant, enter As Variant

    bot.Start "chrome", ""

    bot.Get "https://www.google.com/"

    controlP = (Keys.Control & "p")

    enter = (Keys.enter)

    bot.FindElementByXPath("/html").SendKeys (conrolP)

    bot.FindElementByXPath("/html").SendKeys (enter)

End sub
```

Comment: I have put some points in answer. It would help if you indicated on which line error occured.

Comment: Still no answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the approach you are trying is the way to achieve your goal. However, here are some points:

1. I think the relevant xpath should be `//html`.
2. Use [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) as first line of your module code; You have a typo with `conrolP` which `Option Explicit` would have alerted you to as an undeclared variable.
3. You also don't need those `()` with `SendKeys`.

Comment: I did all the fixes you told me but I am still getting an object required error. I am not sure if the webdriver is catching my Element or it just doesn't recognize what I want to do with it. Thank you for all your help btw!